# Installing Indigo on Mac OS X Maverick boost cannot be found cpp_common

Tags: ros, macbook, boost, compilation, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When installing Indigo on Mac. I get an error stating that Boost cannot be found while compiling cpp_common. Did anyone have the same problem?

Im compiling using:

```
  ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Error:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cpp_common.dir/src/header.cpp.o
In file included from    
/Users/codeporter/Development/indigo/ros_catkin_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/src/header.cpp:35:
/Users/codeporter/Development/indigo/ros_catkin_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/include/ros/header.h:41:10:fatal error: 'boost/shared_array.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/shared_array.hpp> ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_common.dir/src/header.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_common.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'cpp_common': 
Command '/Users/codeporter/Development/indigo/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173515/installing-indigo-on-mac-os-x-maverick-boost-cannot-be-found-cpp_common/) by [CodePorter](https://answers.ros.org/users/18858/codeporter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-06-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have added the following code in "./src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/CMakeLists.txt" and it seems that it has to have compiled correctly:

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "/usr/local/include/")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "/usr/local/include/")
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
   INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
   ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
ENDIF()
```

---

Originally posted by [CodePorter](https://answers.ros.org/users/18858/codeporter/) with karma: 36 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-06-14**:
It is strange that you would have to do this. Can you edit your question with more details about your environment (OS X verison etc) and what steps you followed to install indigo?